# How to get omniToolkitAPI javascript object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, omnichannel

All examples in the documentation I have found for getting the omniToolkitAPI object in lightning show this being done via a lightning component, using a `<lightning:omniToolkitAPI ...>` aura tag in the component which is passed in to a javascript controller that makes the calls, for example here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_setservicepresencestatus.htm

I need to support a situation where a notification arrives from an external service, and I need to react to it by setting the omni channel status for a user via the omniToolkitAPI, so there is no non-hacky way I can see to route this through a lightning component. Is there any way to get hold of the omniToolkitAPI object when the transaction is not triggered by a user action, without the need to use the `<lightning:omniToolkitAPI ...>` tag?

To cut a long story short, I need to be able to programatically set a user's status. I cannot immediately see a way to do this under Lightning, even though it's simple under Classic.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll want to refer to [Salesforce API Resources for External Routing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/omnichannel_external_routing_resources.htm) in the Omnichannel documentation. You'll find links to additional resources to help you integrate partner applications with Omni-Channel including:

- AgentWork
- PendingServiceRouting
- UserServicePresence
- Streaming API Developer Guide
- Streaming API Message Durability
- Streaming API Limits

I suspect one of the 1st three is what you're looking for. Whether to use a SOAP call, a trigger, platform events or something else would depend on the particulars of your situation. The links should help guide you towards a solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it doesn't help. What I would need to do is create a UserServicePresence record, but it seems one is not allowed to do this, though when I saw what you suggested I thought this would work. The original reason I was trying to follow up omniToolkitAPI is that this would give equivalent support to what is available in Classic ... but in lightning there doesn't seem to be a solution. Frustrating. Unless I have misunderstood.

Comment: You didn't say exactly what you needed to do in your question, but I was thinking you could use Streaming API and/or Platform Events to update the UserServicePresence via a simple component since the API allows you to get the Presence. A new one by default is created with a status of `IsAway=true`. I doubt you could clone one.

Comment: crmprogdev thanks. My understanding of the problem has evolved since I asked the question. Essentially what I want to do is create new UserServicePresence records, either via javascript or apex, in Lightning, without requiring actual user input. I can do it in Classic (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_setservicepresencestatus.htm), just not lightning - there is an equivalent method, but the javascript object required doesn't seem to be available without an actual user action. DML inserts are not allowed on UserServicePresence.

Comment: I'm working on a new Lightning Console right now with many new components and features for a client. If I run across anything that might be helpful, I'll be certain to post back.